# Multiple Integral, substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, substitution, multiple-integral

> Solve $\iint_{D}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}dxdy$, where $D=\lbrace (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x>0, \ y<0, \ x^{2}+y^{2}≥\frac{1}{4}, \ x<1+y\rbrace$

I rapresented D and I know that polar coordinates don't work. I know that I need a substitution but I don't find the right one. I though about something like $u(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}, \ v(x,y)=x-y$ but it seems it's not work. I am trying to solve this for hours. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your hint: try polar coordinates again.

[image]

Your region is everything in the fourth quadrant that's both red and blue. You can get your bounds for $\theta$ just based on the fact that you're in Quadrant IV. As for finding bounds on $r$: the lower bound should be easy. If you need a hint for the upper bound on $r$, here it is:

> Write the equation for $x=y+1$ in polar coordinates. How does that help you find the upper bound for $r$?

Hopefully that's enough to help you solve it!

Comment: Maybe $r\in[1/2 , 1]$ ??

Comment: @user782709 that works for $\theta=0$ or $\theta=-\frac\pi 2$, but does it work for $\theta=-\frac\pi 4$?

Comment: In that case I have $\sqrt{2}r=1$ so it doesn't work if r =1...  maybe I have to choose the max of f(x)=cos(θ)-sin(θ) that is -π/4. So I have $r\in [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ is it right?

Comment: f(θ) not f(x). Typo error.

Comment: @user782709 Did you look at the hint in the spoiler box? Find the polar representation of that line, and that'll give you a function for $r$ in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: The polar rapresentation is rcos(θ)=rsin(θ)+1. So I think about r(cos(θ)-sin(θ))=1 and the upper bound of r can be found seeing the max of cos(θ)-sin(θ) and remembering that x<y+1 so r(max)<1. Is it wrong?

Comment: @user782709 It's not quite correct; that function simplifies to $r=\frac1{\cos\theta-\sin\theta}$. That's the polar equation of the line, and it works as an upper bound.

Comment: so the upper bound is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ isn't it?

Comment: @user782709 The upper bound is a function of $\theta$.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thank you!